# NSTimer initWithFireDate not working properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, nstimer

I use `NSTimer` to periodically download data in the background, when wifi is enabled. 
However there is also the option to press a button that downloads the data manually. Therefore  it is possible to enable and disable the autoupdater. 
When a period is "interrupted" by diabling the autoupdate, I want to schedule the next update when the remaining time of this period after the point of time when enabling it is over.
Because NSTimer has no pause method, I use NSTimer's initWithFireDate method.

```
timer = [[NSTimer alloc] initWithFireDate:fireDate interval:updateFrequency target:self selector:@selector(timerTick:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
```

the `fireDate` is definitely after the given date:

```
NSDate *fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:remainingWaitingTime];
```

despite that,the timer is scheduled after the timer's initialization. I am disabling the timer and calculating the remaining time the following way:

```
NSDate *lastFireDate = [timer fireDate];
NSDate *current = [NSDate date];
[timer invalidate];
double timeSinceLastFire = [current timeIntervalSinceDate:lastFireDate];
remainingWaitingTime = updateFrequency - timeSinceLastFire;
```

The calculated time (remainingWaitingTime) has a correct value.

What am I doing wrong?

Best Regards,
Fabian

Comment: I'm sorry, but it's very difficult to understand what you're saying.  What specifically is wrong?

Comment: Are you saying timerTick: is never called by your timer?

Answer (score 1):

You have to add your timer to the run loop by doing the following:

```
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer: timer forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
```